# How to Delay a Javascript Function Until it is in the middle of web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have a number animation on my web page and I dont want the animation to start until it is in the middle of the web page. I tried to google onscroll and other options but I could not get this to work properly.

I prefer for the animation not to start until the visitor has scrolled down to 472px. As of right now as soon as the web page loads the number animation starts automatically. Any help I would really appreciate it.

```js
// 472 px  -  Starts Yellow Counter Section

const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const speed = 200; // The lower the slower

counters.forEach(counter => {
 const updateCount = () => {
  const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
  const count = +counter.innerText;

  // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
  const inc = target / speed;

  // console.log(inc);
  // console.log(count);

  // Check if target is reached
  if (count < target) {
   // Add inc to count and output in counter
   counter.innerText = count + inc;
   // Call function every ms
   setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
  } else {
   counter.innerText = target;
  }
 };

 updateCount();
});
```

```css
.bg-yellow-white {
    background: #f7c51e;
    color: white;
}


.container {
    max-width: 1404px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.l-heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}





/* Padding */

.py-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.py-2 {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.py-3 {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}


/* All Around Padding */

.p-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-2 {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.p-3 {
    padding: 3rem;
}

 /*  ======================== Red Block ======================== */


 .red-block {

    height: 472px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 }


 /*  ======================== PROJECS COMPLETED  ======================== */

#projects-completed .container .items {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

#projects-completed .container .items .item .circle {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-block">

    <p>red block</p>

</div>



<section id="projects-completed" class="counters bg-yellow-white">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item text-center p-3">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="counter l-heading" data-target="1750">500</div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="py-2">Projects Completed</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item text-center p-3">
                <div class="circle py-2">
                    <div class="l-heading counter" data-target="5">500</div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="py-2">Staff Members</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="item text-center p-3">
                <div class="circle">
                    <h3 class="l-heading ">1750</h3>
                </div>
                <h2 class="py-2">Projects Completed</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item text-center p-3">
                <div class="circle py-2">
                    <h3 class="l-heading">5</h3>
                </div>
                <h2 class="py-2">Staff Members</h2>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `onscroll and other options but I could not get this to work properly.`  It might be an idea to show us your attempt at using `onscroll`.

Comment: You could use setTimeout to call a function periodically. That function could check the current scroll position and start your animation if it is above a desired value. If not the function could setTimeout again and try later until is is successful.

Answer (score 1):

wesbos has great video on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzRsENVD3W8&list=PLu8EoSxDXHP6CGK4YVJhL_VWetA865GOH&index=14&t=0s

Basically what you need to do is listen for scroll and check where user currently is compared to desired place in px

you can check code here and adjust it to your needs https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/blob/master/13%20-%20Slide%20in%20on%20Scroll/index-FINISHED.html

Answer (score 0):

By using `jquery` , first add this reference script above your `js` code or referenece script

```html
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></scrip>
....
</head>
```

if you want the code to launch specifically after `472 px`:

js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
Let initialScroll = true;
//you can decrease or increase 472 depending on where exactly 
//you want your function to be called 

    $(document).scroll(function () {

        if (($(document).scrollTop() > 472)&& initialScroll) {
           //call your function here
            console.log( "reached 472")
InitialScroll=false;
        }
    });
});
```

if you want your function to start after reaching the middle
of the document
you place a `div` where the middle of the html code is :

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
<div id="middle"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
Let initialScroll=true
    $(document).scroll(function () {

        if (($(document).scrollTop() >=$('#middle').position().top)&&initialScroll) {
           //call your function here
            console.log( "reached middle")
InitialScroll=false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both your codes but I get same error. It says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add jquery reference . Add this script in head <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>. I will edit the answer

Comment: I also added a condition so your function be called one time only after scrolling to the wanted target. This will work for sure, recheck my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `getBoundingClientRect()`. `document.querySelector( 'some element' ).getBoundingClientRect()` will give you the properties of the specific element

for Example if you want to start an animation when an element is visible to user on his screen ( in the visible viewport ), you can use this to call the function and start the animation

```
    let calledStatus = 0; // some flag variable to remember if function is called
    window.onscroll  = function(){ 
        element =  document.querySelector( '.some element' );
        clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        if( clientRect.top < window.innerHeight && clientRect.top > ( clientRect.height * -1) && calledStatus == 0){
            //call your function or do other stuff
            console.log('called' )
              calledStatus = 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: That was just an example on how you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`  for your situation   .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code copy pasted, but it should give you a clue on how it should work:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));
  let active = false;

  const lazyLoad = function() {
    if (active === false) {
      active = true;

      setTimeout(function() {
        lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
          if ((lazyImage.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight && lazyImage.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 0) && getComputedStyle(lazyImage).display !== "none") {
            lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
            lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
            lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");

            lazyImages = lazyImages.filter(function(image) {
              return image !== lazyImage;
            });

            if (lazyImages.length === 0) {
              document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyLoad);
              window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyLoad);
              window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoad);
            }
          }
        });

        active = false;
      }, 200);
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyLoad);
  window.addEventListener("resize", lazyLoad);
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoad);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a native javascript API for "listetning" where the user currently is on the page called [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Basically you set a callback which should execute once the desired content scrolls into view.

It's used for all those fancy page animations where cards appear once you start scrolling to the bottom of the page since it's far more efficient than listening on the scroll event.

Kevin Powell did a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8EYosX4NOo) about this topic.

Hope it helps!